# How to set default tab on page load using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How can i set the default tab in below code.For example:i need to set default tab as third tab on page load using jquery mobile.Any immediate response will be appreciated`enter code here` 
[refer below fiddle][1]
 http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/mktgnp3e/

Comment: You need to use `active` options like `.tabs({ active: 2})`. Checkout the documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the active property in the object you pass to the tabs function to the index of the tab you want to make default. Index starts at 0. So to make the third tab the default:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    active: 2,
    activate: function (event, ui) {
      var active = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');
      $("#tabid").html('the tab id is ' + $("#tabs ul>li a").eq(active).attr("href"));
    }
});
```

[Here is an example codepen.](https://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/vmyJBd)